# Sharing state between threads with notify-rs

Tags: rust

i'm new to rust.

I'm trying to write a file_sensor that will start a counter after a file is created. The plan is that after an amount of time, if a second file is not received the sensor will exit with a zero exit code.

I could write the code to continue that work but i feel the code below illustrates the problem (i have also missed for example the post function referred to)

I have been struggling with this problem for several hours, i've tried Arc and mutex's and even global variables.

The Timer implementation is [Ticktock-rs](https://docs.rs/ticktock/latest/ticktock/timer/index.html)

I need to be able to either get heartbeat in the match body for EventKind::Create(CreateKind::Folder) or file_count in the loop

The code i've attached here runs but file_count is always zero in the loop.

```
use std::env;
use std::path::Path;
use std::{thread, time};
use std::process::ExitCode;
use ticktock::Timer;
use notify::{ 
    Watcher, 
    RecommendedWatcher, 
    RecursiveMode, 
    Result, 
    event::{EventKind, CreateKind, ModifyKind, Event}
};


fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let now = time::Instant::now();
    let mut heartbeat = Timer::apply(
        |_, count| {
            *count += 1;
            *count
        },
        0,
    )
    .every(time::Duration::from_millis(500))
    .start(now);
    let mut file_count = 0;
    let args = Args::parse();
    let REQUEST_SENSOR_PATH = env::var("REQUEST_SENSOR_PATH").expect("$REQUEST_SENSOR_PATH} is not set");
    let mut watcher = notify::recommended_watcher(move|res: Result<Event>| {
        match res {
           Ok(event) => {
            match event.kind {
                EventKind::Create(CreateKind::File) => {   
                    file_count += 1;
                    // do something with file
                }
                _ => { /* something else changed */ }
            }
            println!("{:?}", event);

           },
           Err(e) => {
            println!("watch error: {:?}", e);
            ExitCode::from(101);
           },
        }
    })?;

    watcher.watch(Path::new(&REQUEST_SENSOR_PATH), RecursiveMode::Recursive)?;

    loop {
        let now = time::Instant::now();
        if let Some(n) = heartbeat.update(now){
            println!("Heartbeat: {}, fileCount: {}", n, file_count);
            if n > 10 {
                heartbeat.set_value(0);
                // This function will reset timer when a file arrives
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Yours is missing a lot of `use` statements which aren't easy to recreate (like `Result<()>`, which could be anything)

Comment: @Finomnis thats updated

Comment: Please verify that your code behaves as you claim. When I compile your code, it gives me `use of undeclared type \`Args\``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler warnings show you the problem:

```
warning: unused variable: `file_count`
  --> src/main.rs:31:25
   |
31 |                         file_count += 1;
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default
   = help: did you mean to capture by reference instead?
```

The problem here is that you use `file_count` inside of a `move ||` closure. `file_count` is an `i32`, which is `Copy`. Using it in a `move ||` closure actually creates a copy of it, which does no longer update the original variable if you assign to it.

Either way, it's impossible to modify a variable in `main()` from an event handler. Event handlers require `'static` lifetime if they reference things, because Rust cannot guarantee that the event handler lives shorter than `main`.

One solution for this problem is to use reference counters and interior mutability. In this case, I will use `Arc` for reference counters and `AtomicI32` for interior mutability. Note that `notify::recommended_watcher` requires thread safety, otherwise instead of an `Arc<AtomicI32>` we could have used an `Rc<Cell<i32>>`, which is the same thing but only for single-threaded environments, with a little less overhead.

```rust
use notify::{
    event::{CreateKind, Event, EventKind},
    RecursiveMode, Result, Watcher,
};
use std::time;
use std::{env, sync::atomic::Ordering};
use std::{path::Path, sync::Arc};
use std::{process::ExitCode, sync::atomic::AtomicI32};
use ticktock::Timer;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let now = time::Instant::now();
    let mut heartbeat = Timer::apply(
        |_, count| {
            *count += 1;
            *count
        },
        0,
    )
    .every(time::Duration::from_millis(500))
    .start(now);
    let file_count = Arc::new(AtomicI32::new(0));

    let REQUEST_SENSOR_PATH =
        env::var("REQUEST_SENSOR_PATH").expect("$REQUEST_SENSOR_PATH} is not set");
    let mut watcher = notify::recommended_watcher({
        let file_count = Arc::clone(&file_count);
        move |res: Result<Event>| {
            match res {
                Ok(event) => {
                    match event.kind {
                        EventKind::Create(CreateKind::File) => {
                            file_count.fetch_add(1, Ordering::AcqRel);
                            // do something with file
                        }
                        _ => { /* something else changed */ }
                    }
                    println!("{:?}", event);
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("watch error: {:?}", e);
                    ExitCode::from(101);
                }
            }
        }
    })?;

    watcher.watch(Path::new(&REQUEST_SENSOR_PATH), RecursiveMode::Recursive)?;

    loop {
        let now = time::Instant::now();
        if let Some(n) = heartbeat.update(now) {
            println!(
                "Heartbeat: {}, fileCount: {}",
                n,
                file_count.load(Ordering::Acquire)
            );
            if n > 10 {
                heartbeat.set_value(0);
                // This function will reset timer when a file arrives
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, note that the `ExitCode::from(101);` gives you a warning. It does not actually exit the program, it only creates an exit code variable and then discards it again. You probably intended to write `std::process::exit(101);`. Although I would discourage it, because it does not properly clean up (does not call any `Drop` implementations). I'd use `panic` here, instead. This is the exact usecase `panic` is meant for.

Comment: thanks @finomnis for taking the time to write this greate well structured answer. Would you mind editing it to add what you would do in order to get heratbeat in the match?

Comment: @HappyMachine I'm not entirely sure what you mean with that :)

Comment: So - if you wanted to be able to execute hearbeat.update(now) from inside the  EventKind::Create(CreateKind::File) callback

Comment: @HappyMachine I have never worked with the `ticktock` crate before. I also don't think you are using it right; you are running it in an endless loop, basically an idle-wait, which can't be right. So I'd say, I don't. You should probably open a new question, as it would be off-topic for this one.